# How to include many shared libraries .so to build android apk

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, java-native-interface

I want to use tow `extern` library to build android application of tracking object with surf algorithm so I used this tutorial [Using OpenCV Nonfree Module (SIFT, SURF) in Android NDK Projects](https://sites.google.com/site/wghsite/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android)

the first library is `libobjtrack_opencv_jni.so` (using for tracking) an the 2 others are libopencv_java.so and `libobjtrack_opencv_jni.so`
I finished To Get this result:

**Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := sift_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv_java_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libopencv_java.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := objtrack_opencv_jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libobjtrack_opencv_jni.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE        := STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
include C:/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= C:/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := test_sift12
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror -O3 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := sift_prebuilt opencv_java_prebuilt objtrack_opencv_jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test_sift.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

build is succeeded and i got `test_sift12.so` but is not work when i run the `.apk` .. I think that the problem is with the use of `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` in `android.mk` file .
i need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load library, where you want to use that libraries in the activity.

like in this way

```
public class YourClassName extends Activity {

.....

//add the following code at the end of the class


  static 
  {
      System.loadlibrary("opencv_java");
      System.loadlibrary("objtrack_opencv_jni");
      System.loadlibrary("nonfree");
      System.loadlibrary("test_sift12");
   }
}
```

I suggest you change you names of following

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := sift_prebuilt
```

to

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree
```

and

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv_java_prebuilt
```

to

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv_java
```

Remember don't forget to modify the names in `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`